# How to incrementally add linear regression column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got an example pandas dataframe like this:

```
     a    b
0  6.0  0.6
1  1.0  0.3
2  3.0  0.8
3  5.0  0.1
4  7.0  0.4
5  2.0  0.2
6  0.0  0.9
7  4.0  0.7
8  8.0  0.0
9  9.0  0.5
```

I want to add a new column, `linear` to the column, which is the linear regression output of fit a on b. Now I got:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
repr = LinearRegression()
repr.fit(df['a'].as_matrix().reshape(-1,1),df['b'].as_matrix().reshape(-1,1))
repr.predict(df['a'].as_matrix().reshape(-1,1)) # This will give the linear regression outcome for whole column
```

Now I want to incrementally do linear regression on series `a`, so the first entry of `linear` will be `b[0]`, and the second will be `b[0]/a[0]*a[1]`, and the third will be the linear regression outcome of the first two entries, and so on and so forth. I have no clue how to do that with pandas, except for iterating through all the entries, is there a batter way?

Comment: can you post sample output?

Comment: BTW, use `repr.fit(df[['a']],df['b'])` and `repr.predict(df[['a']])` for `fit` and `predict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) with some custom apply functions. Interesting way to do LR...

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""     a    b
0  6.0  0.6
1  1.0  0.3
2  3.0  0.8
3  5.0  0.1
4  7.0  0.4
5  2.0  0.2
6  0.0  0.9
7  4.0  0.7
8  8.0  0.0
9  9.0  0.5
10 10.0 0.4
11 11.0 0.35
12 12.0 0.3
13 13.0 0.28
14 14.0 0.27
15 15.0 0.22"""), sep='\s+')
df = df.sort_values(by='a')
ax = df.plot(x='a',y='b',kind='scatter')
m, b = np.polyfit(df['a'],df['b'],1)
lin_reg = lambda x, m, b : m*x + b 
df['lin'] = lin_reg(df['a'], m, b)
def make_m(x):
    y = df['b'].iloc[0:len(x)]
    return np.polyfit(x, y, 1)[0]
def make_b(x):
    y = df['b'].iloc[0:len(x)]
    return np.polyfit(x, y, 1)[1]
df['new'] = df['a'].expanding().apply(make_m, raw=True)*df['a'] + df['a'].expanding().apply(make_b, raw=True)
# df = df.sort_values(by='a')
ax.plot(df.a,df.lin)
ax.plot(df.a,df.new)
```

[image: Iterative Linear Regression]

Comment: You can see a cool result where it is converging to the overall linear regression if you use some more data ^^^.